# Confirmação de envio de email?

Tags: c#, asp.net, envio-de-email

Preciso enviar e-mails para os clientes da minha empresa, porém preciso saber também se estes e-mails forma recebidos com sucesso.

- Tem alguma forma de fazer?
- Qual seria a melhor?

Seria algo parecido com *Whats App*, ou seja, quando a mensagem for visualizada\lida me retornaria algo, o *Whats App* aparece dois riscos azuis.

Comment: @Marconi, caso todos os seus clientes usem um Cliente de Email (como o Outlook, Thunderbird, etc), você pode setar a propriedade [`MailMessage.DeliveryNotificationOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.deliverynotificationoptions.aspx) para [`DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.deliverynotificationoptions.aspx) e adicionar um email de notificação a propriedade [`MailMessage.ReplyToList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.replytolist(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @TobyMosque Manda ver em um resposta, pode ser que ajude alguém. Desconhecia essas propriedades.

Comment: @Marconi, sinceramente não acho esta propriedade muito util, ela basicamente lhe envia um email de confimação e funciona apenas se o Usuario usar um Cliente de Email que não seja Web.

Comment: @TobyMosque entendi, mais de qualquer forma já é uma grande ajuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é possível pois o protocolo *SMTP* não garante entrega de emails. Veja nesse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095104/how-to-confirm-that-mail-has-been-delivered-or-not) para obter mais explicações.

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível saber com certeza se alguém recebeu ou leu um e-mail, mas uma alternativa simples é colocar um link para a mensagem real, então você pode verificar se o link foi acessado ou não.

Answer (score 3):

Como outros já disseream antes, o protoloco SMTP não garante que a mensagem será entregue, e nem que o Cliente de Email irá enviar uma notificação de que a mensagem foi recebida.

Porém, alguns clientes de Email (como o `Outlook` ou o `Thunderbird`) são capazes de intepretar o Header `Disposition-Notification-To` e enviar uma notificação.

```
public void PrepararNotificacoes(ref MailMessage mensagem)
{
    mensagem.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure | DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess | DeliveryNotificationOptions.Delay;
    mensagem.Headers.Add("Disposition-Notification-To", "toby.mosque@googlemail.com");
}
```

Neste caso a notificação não será enviada para uma URL, mas para um email, e mesmo que o email seja recebido, não há garantias que o email de notificação será enviado ou que chegará ao destino.

Como alternativa para automatizar este processo, você pode criar um serviço POP3 que receba os emails de notificação, este serviço pode escrever no seu Banco, criar um Cliente WCF, etc... desta forma você conseguiria registrar que o email foi lido.

Answer (score 0):

**Sim** tem como.
Utilizando a ferramenta [Mautic](https://br.mautic.org/).

O Mautic é uma ferramenta de Automação de marketing, ele tem uma funcionalidade que te atenderia que seria o envio de email para uma lista de clientes.Quando você envia emails com o mautic, você consegue saber a hora exata que o cliente recebeu e quando abriu.

Com esta ferramenta dá pra fazer campanhas de marketing entre outras coisas. E o melhor é Open source e gratuita.

O único ponto negativo é que a documentação só tem em inglês.
Mas tem a comunidade no Facebook que pode estar te auxiliando.

Comment: Opa funciona em .net? Tem como postar um exemplo?

Comment: Marconi, o mautic é uma plataforma web, mas dentro dela tem uma api só que eu ainda não utilizei esta api. só a parte web de envio de email e gerenciamento de campanha de marketing.

Comment: Entendi, vou estudar melhor com ela funciona.

Comment: Aqui está o grupo do facebook https://www.facebook.com/groups/mautic.brasil/

Answer (score 0):

Existe um cliente de e-mail open-source chamado [Mailspring](https://getmailspring.com), que possui um recurso de confirmação de leitura baseado em uma imagem.

Basicamente, ele possui uma imagem de 1x1px da cor do fundo do e-mail com um listener no link, que permite saber quando a imagem foi baixada, e retorna um alerta para o e-mail que enviou.

O bônus é que, ao contrário da `Confirmação de leitura` do Outlook, ele não pede permissão para o receptor antes de enviar a confirmação. O ônus é que se o receptor da mensagem não tiver a opção `Baixar automaticamente todas as imagens` habilitada no e-mail e não clicar em alguma imagem do seu e-mail para `Baixar imagens`, o link não funciona.